# amount of generated JLabels seems random on each start

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I am trying generate a JLabel grid in Java, but on every start the generated JLabels vary, on one start of the program there can be 25 visual JLabels, and without changing the code and restarting there can be 27 visual JLabels, im so confused, I have no idea what might be causing this. In theory there should be 169 JLabels visual on the screen (13 x 13 grid).

```
public class GUI {

    JFrame frame;
    JPanel panel;
    
    int matrixLength = 13;

    JLabel label[] = new JLabel[matrixLength * matrixLength];

    public GUI() {

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);

        panel = (JPanel) frame.getContentPane();
        panel.setLayout(null);

        for (JLabel labels : label) {
            labels = new JLabel();
            labels.setVisible(true);
        }

    }

    public void drawLabels() {
        
        int xInc = 50;
        int yInc = 50;

        int xStart = 50;
        int yStart = 0;

        int y = yStart;
        int x = 50;

        for (int i = 0; i < label.length; i++) {
            label[i] = new JLabel(" ");
            label[i].setOpaque(true);
            label[i].setVisible(true);
            label[i].setBackground(Color.black);

            if (i % (matrixLength) == 0) {
                y += yInc;
                x = xStart;
            } else {
                x += xInc;
            }

            System.out.println("i: " + i + " | y: " + y + " | x: " + x);

            label[i].setBounds(x, y, 40, 40);
            panel.add(label[i]);

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created the following GUI from your code.

[image: JLabel Grid GUI]

Here are the changes I made.

1. I added a `main` method so I could start the application.  In the `main` method, I called the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method to ensure that the Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).
2. I used two [Swing layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) to create the GUI.  The `JFrame` has a default `BorderLayout`.  The `JPanel` I created to hold the `JLabels` uses a `GridLayout`.
3. I added a text value to each of the `JLabels` so you could see them in the grid.

Here's the complete runnable code I used to create the GUI.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class LabelGridGUI {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new LabelGridGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    JFrame frame;

    int matrixLength = 13;

    JLabel label[] = new JLabel[matrixLength * matrixLength];

    public LabelGridGUI() {
        frame = new JFrame("Label Grid");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(createLabelPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public JPanel createLabelPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, matrixLength));

        for (int i = 0; i < label.length; i++) {
            label[i] = new JLabel("X");
            label[i].setBackground(Color.black);
            label[i].setForeground(Color.yellow);
            label[i].setOpaque(true);
            panel.add(label[i]);
        }

        return panel;
    }

}
```